# Dask dataframe groupby-agg with known divisions

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

When running groupby-agg on a Dask dataframe, the resulting Dask dataframe is not indexed. If the groupby is run on a single column, is it possible to achieve an indexed Dask dataframe?

```py
from dask.datasets import timeseries
df = timeseries()
a = df.groupby('name').agg('sum')
print(a.known_divisions)  # False
```

To get the indexed dataframe, it's possible to do:

```py
b = a.reset_index().set_index('name')
print(b.known_divisions)  # True
```

However, the `.set_index` operation will shuffle data, which might be possible to avoid at the time of groupby-agg.

Is there any other set of operations that will eventually give the aggregated dataframe such that `a.known_divisions==True`?

Update: the specific use case I have in mind is when the unique values of name column are known (and there could be many, many unique values). For example, pretend there is a million names, then it would be great to get the groupby-agg result, so that all names starting with 'A' are in one partition, with 'B' in second partition, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify - this falls squarely in the "difficult cases" section of the [groupby docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html), and the index can't be known without some reshuffling & computation. Are you suggesting that there could be an  extra argument to groupby to trigger just enough computation to know the index? `df.reset_index().set_index()` definitely isn't an elegant operation.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question... I'm really thinking of a case where the unique values of name column are known in advance (I will update the question with this clarification). Maybe this is not feasible, though...

Comment: if you first call `df = df.categorize(['name'])` the categories will be known heading into the grouby. And the resulting index is a known categorical index. but the divisions are still not known. it seems from the [categoricals](//docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-categoricals.html) docs that a known categorical column stores the set of categories in `_meta`, but I don't think it stores group statistics. So having the divisions be known would still require computation & reshuffle. So I'm not sure that this behavior is all that unexpected now that I'm digging into it.

Comment: still, I think a flag to set the index in the `.groupby` command would be a nice feature :)